# Spark performance when using FlatMap Function

Tags: apache-spark

I am a little bit new to Spark and am struggling to understand its system and distributed behavior.

I wrote the simple codes as below and test it on the spark version `2.0.1`.

As I expected, it worked fine.

However, the worker nodes behavior makes me have a question here.

I have one spark master and four worker nodes. When running my codes, the strange thing is that all the worker nodes didn't work. Just two of them were allocated and executed. Moreover, the data was not evenly distributed into the two worker nodes. The total data is about 700Mb and the data size that the two worker nodes were allocated was 150Mb and 550Mb respectivey. I want them to have equal data size but Spark automatically had the two workers have different data size.

So, my question is as below.

1. How to use all the worker nodes when running spark-submit? Although using two worker nodes is more efficient, I want to use them all.
2. How to evenly distribute the data into four nodes? I don't want the the worker nodes have unbalanced data size.

Below is my simple code. It is very straightforward, so I skipped detailed explanation.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by dst on 2/1/17.
 */

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String inputFile = args[0];
        String outputFile = args[1];
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("jrdd-dt-ctor")
                .set("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");


        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);


        JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile(inputFile);


        JavaRDD<String> newLine = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
            public Iterator<String> call(String s) throws Exception {
                List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> ls = Arrays.asList(s.split("\t"));

                String values = ls.get(ls.size()-1);
                List<String> value = Arrays.asList(values.split("\\|"));

                for(int i=0;i<value.size();++i){
                    String ns = ls.get(0)+"\t"+ls.get(1)+"\t"+ls.get(2)+"\t"+ls.get(3)+"\t"+ls.get(4)+"\t"+ls.get(5);
                    ns = ns + "\t" + value.get(i);
                    ret.add(ns);
                }
                return ret.iterator();
            }
        });


        newLine.saveAsTextFile(outputFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check the number of partitions in lines? could it be just 2?

Comment: Not likely. I didn't set the number of partitions. However, If the data size is larger than that I used, all the worker nodes worked.